# TFS Build definition to run tests without using Lab Management

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2013 and need to know if I can setup a build to run unit tests without the need to use Lab Management.  I don't have the ability to setup the Lab Management but want the build when completed to run the unit tests associated with it.  Is that possible?  If so, where are the tests run?  Would the same be true with Coded-UI tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running unit tests from the build server is straight forward.  Under the process tab in the build definition, go to 2. Basic > Automated Tests.  There you can filter by filename or select a test settings file.

If you want to run Coded UI Tests from the build there are two options.

The first is to configure the unit test run to run the tests interactively.  This will allow CUIT tests to run.  Basically they will run like you would run them from Visual Studio.  I wrote this post for TFS 2010, but it hasn't changed for TFS 2013.
http://www.codesmartnothard.com/2010/10/04/ConfiguringATFS2010TeamBuildServerToRunCodedUITests.aspx

The other option requires you to modify the build template and add an ExecuteRemoteTestRun activity to the end of the definition.  This allows you to choose the test suites that contain the test cases with associated automation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff934562.aspx#bkmk_executeremotetestrun

Let me know if you have any questions about these options.

Mike

Comment: The first link doesn't appear to be working for me. I had a question, would your solution for coded UI tests work for VS 2015?